# Prevent user from typing and pasting in text field and allow reading from a USB Barcode reader only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an HTML input field like:

```
<input type="text" name="TextBox1" id="TextBox1">
```

I want to prevent typing using keyboard and pasting using mouse, while at the same time allow only input from a USB barcode reader to be entered.
I tried using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    $('#TextBox1').keydown(function(e) { 
        if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }                  
    });    
});
```

But it will prevent input from every source including USB barcode scanner also.

Any suggestions? Is it possible?

Comment: Why not combining user input and barcode input? If you find a barcode, you e.g. add the product. If not, you do a search over your products.

Comment: PS: I hope you understand that your js code will garantee nothing in terms of source of the input? There are some signs like low input delay (not sure if it doesn't paste the whole code at once), mentioned by Zsolt Szilagy can be used to differ user input and scanner, but it doesn't mean that the user can't work around your restrictions on the client side. In fact, anyone can, easily, so don't use it as a validation.

Answer (score 2):

When using the barcode scanner, you can expect that the field gets filled withhin some hundred ms, while humans need at least one or two seconds to type 10 digits. When the first digit gets entered you could set a timeout of e.g. 300ms. If the required value length is not rached withhin 
300ms, just clear the field.

This does not prevent someone fraudly entering random digits at high speed, but after all, never trust user data.

edit: no code snippet at hand, but the pseudocode might be

```
on keydown
    if(value.length < 2)
        timeout = now+300
    elseif(now > timeout and value-legth < required legth)
        value=''
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what event the barcode scanner raises, but have you tried this:

```
<input type="text" name="TextBox1" id="TextBox1" onkeydown="return false;">
```

Comment: so i'm guessing the barcode scanner simulates key keystroke. if you look at the keycode of the event, what values do you get?